# C drive is full but without data

Tags: disk-space, robocopy

My C drive has 100 GB capacity with around 60 GB free space. Two months ago I created an imaginary drive Y with 2 GB capacity to copy certain files from another computer. The files are being copied by Robocopy upon running a small batch file.

One week ago I noticed drive Y is almost full and the C drive was also full. I tried to delete the drive Y, but Y didn't go that time. When I restarted the computer the Y drive disappeared but C was still almost full. I did some clean-up and now the empty space is just 4 GB. C drive Properties shows data only for 32 GB. Out of 100 GB the empty space should be around 60 GB. This is my office computer and only essential office work software is installed. How to recover the full free space?

Comment: Did you try scandisk? Please [edit] your question about that. Also please improve your grammar, especially uppercase letters where appropriate. Well-readable questions have better chance to get answers. Lazy writers tend to get low attention.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by *imaginary drive* and how you have created it.

Answer (score 0):

Use TreeSize to find what is consuming space

https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Wouldn't the plain text "TreeSize" be sufficient to be considered "essential parts"? My answer is not "link-only".